# Extracting date and time from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which there is a field last_update_date in which the date is displayed in short form like 25/02/2015.If I want to extract the date in long date time format like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss how can I do so.Please help on how can I query the data from this table by using to_date or extract function.

Comment: It's always extracted as a full date/time value. Your client tool must have a formatting issue. Alternatively, use `TO_DATE()` to see the time part as well.

Comment: 1. Oracle is not MySQL and MySQL is not Oracle (in terms of DBMS). Please, apply a single DBMS tag. 2. Date in Oracle is always stored with seconds. Data display is another task: you may use `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter or use `to_char` function to display a date in full format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value as a `DATE` data type then use:

```sql
SELECT last_update_date FROM table_name
```

If the client application is not showing the time component then you need to modify the formatting preferences of the client application; you should **NOT** need to modify the query.

For example, SQL*Plus and SQL Developer both use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the default format for **displaying** dates and that can be modified using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Other client applications are going to have different ways of setting their formatting and you will need to consult the appropriate manuals/guides for those applications.

---

If you want the value as a formatted string (and not as a `DATE`) then use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(last_update_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS formatted_date
FROM   table_name
```